# TileMill: Can't use both background-color and background-image?

Tags: tilemill, mapbox, cartocss

Very new to TileMill and am working on my first project. I'm using a pattern image to enhance some areas on the map, water being an example.  I've added the pattern to the water areas on my layers, and am now trying to match the background to those areas.  Having trouble - can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This renders only the pattern in the map preview, but not the background color as well:

```
Map { 
  background-color:@Water;
  background-image:url(images/water.png);
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have only one of those. But you can open an image editor and overlay the `water.png` on that color, thus reaching your goal.

An alternative solution would be downloading water polygons instead of land polygons. I don't know which one do you use, but polygons made from OpenStreetMap data can be downloaded from [openstreetmapdata.org](http://openstreetmapdata.com/). Then use the solution that's in your screenshot for reservoirs.